# Turn off NX caching in vscode

Tags: nrwl-nx

How do you turn off all caching in NX?

Using vscode and the nx plugin. I'm not sure how caching was enabled, and now I don't know how to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the documentation examples on how enable/disable it for NX version below and above 17 here:
https://nx.dev/features/cache-task-results#define-cacheable-tasks

Exmaple for version 17 and higher:
in the nx.json

```
{
  "targetDefaults": {
    "build": {
      "cache": true // switch true/false here
    },
    "test": {
      "cache": true
    }
  }
}
```

for version 17 and lower:
in the nx.json

```
{
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "nx/tasks-runners/default",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": ["build", "test"] // add/remove here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usually after the 16 version it's enabled automatically when a workspace generated.

Alternatively you can run command with skip cache using:
`nx build header --skip-nx-cache`
checkout here: https://nx.dev/features/cache-task-results#turn-off-or-skip-the-cache